# Yellow colored questions in EE stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, questions

Why there are few  questions which has yellow background instead of normal white in EE stackexchange. Is there any priority or something? Is this something related to the new design? What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: Does it still show up that way? It doesn't here. Also the answerer of the question isn't displayed on your screenshot, what browser and version are you using?

Comment: @PlasmaHH that's just an attempt to redact Olin's name I suspect, you can see part of O....p although with 153k it wouldn't be too successful even if necessary ;)

Comment: I thought I should not disclose the name.

Comment: it's pinkish though, not yellow. Might wanna check your monitor's output calibrations

Comment: but the color looks like `light yellow`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens when a question contains one of your favorite tags, so you must have one of microcontroller, audio or embedded selected under your favorite tags. I'm pretty sure it has been a feature quite a while (although I don't use it myself) so maybe the color scheme has just changed under the new layout which makes it more apparent. But I guess more likely you've probably just added some favorite tags?

Comment: This is correct, a question with a favourite tag gets highlighted, even before the design update it was like this, but as everything was more yellowish it didn't stand out as much.

Comment: That's awesome.! I actually became curious because recently I posted a question and it's background changed